# Find all files on the filesystem that I have edited or created

Tags: files

In Ubuntu, is it possible to obtain a list of all files on the filesystem that I have edited? I need some way to find all the files that I have modified or written (because these files tend to be the most important to me, and I need a way to identify them so that I won't accidentally delete them.)

Answer (score -1):

Using `find` command you can list the files created/edited by a user.

```
find / -mtime -10 -type f -user userid -print
```

This will search all the files created/edited in last 10 days.

use `sudo` if you are searching the files under `/` file system and if it's only your home directory(`$HOME`) ignore sudo command.

Comment: Does this work for **edit**? I mean, the `-user userid` is only for files that are owned by you, if you have edited a file that is owned by the system or another user, you won't find it.

Comment: This wont work if the we use sudo <command> to edit the file. This command can only list the files that are owned by a particular user

Comment: also, world or group writeable files: you don't need sudo for that :)

Comment: I agree but if sudo is not used then OP would get "permission denied" for searching `/` file system. Sudo is just to suppress the warnings.

Comment: @devav2 the list includes thousands of Nautilus thumbnails it created under your name. Also programs you've downloaded by never changed such as `EnhanceIO` also show up on the list.