# How do I find all system files I've edited with `gedit`?

Tags: gedit, log

At first I was going to ask the question "Find all files I've created / changed after installation?" but that is a duplicate of ([Find all files on the filesystem that I have edited or created](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217477/find-all-files-on-the-filesystem-that-i-have-edited-or-created)) which doesn't have a satisfactory answer because it includes stuff downloaded and never changed plus thousands of thumbnails Nautilus has created under my user ID unbeknownst to me.

The reason for this need is I had written a nifty script to power-off a USB port on my laptop that always has power in order to win a bounty.

Now I'm very displeased that my **always powered on USB port by design** is powered off during suspend or shutdown. I want to track down and revert the programs those systemd configurations I setup with `gedit`. Having a poor memory for impromptu things I can't remember what I changed.

**How do I find all the files I've created or changed with `gedit`?**

I have created a wrapper script called `gsu` that uses `pkexec` to replace `gksu gedit` ([How can I create new "gksu" command based on pkexec?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/847768/how-can-i-create-new-gksu-command-based-on-pkexec)). I will change it to log all system files edited with their last date.

In the mean time someone hinted on that link all sudo commands using gedit were logged someplace. The question is where and how to succiently list them with `grep` or whatever?

Please note I can find this through other time-consuming means but feel this is an important question many others may have as well.

Comment: :) You fall in same pit as I did before. I have learned to leave a special tag wherever I change something in configuration like my old username `##sneetsher: comment` or `//sneetsher: comment` so I can collect them using `grep` before reinstalling or upgrade. But if all your edits are using `gedit`, gedit by default leaves a hidden backup file, its filename ends with `~`.  So you may find your edited files among the output of  `sudo updatedb; locate -br ~$`

Comment: Actually I put comments on almost all scripts whenever I change them with reasons why. Then I log the script name into a spreadsheet that cat's the code with 'grep' command and dumps the output in neighbouring cells. In this case with the bounty question for another person, I did not :(

Answer (score 2):

I just edited a "system" file using this command to open the file:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
```

I immediately then looked at the last entry in `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` and saw this:

```
  <bookmark href="file:///etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini" added="2016-11-14T02:04:05Z" modified="2016-11-14T02:04:05Z" visited="2016-11-14T02:04:05Z">
    <info>
      <metadata owner="http://freedesktop.org">
        <mime:mime-type type="text/plain"/>
        <bookmark:groups>
          <bookmark:group>gedit</bookmark:group>
        </bookmark:groups>
        <bookmark:applications>
          <bookmark:application name="gedit" exec="&apos;gedit %u&apos;" modified="2016-11-14T02:04:05Z" count="1"/>
        </bookmark:applications>
      </metadata>
    </info>
  </bookmark>
```

Limitations:

- the `recently-used.xbel` contents don't reveal how you invoked `gedit`.
- it's not necessary that a file should have been edited or created with `gedit`; merely viewing a file with `gedit` gets the file listed.

---

Visual inspection of the file seems safer than using code to extract the needed information. Something like `grep -B5 '<bookmark:group>gedit</bookmark:group>' recently-used.xbel | grep 'bookmark href=' | grep -v '///home/'` may help isolate system files that were edited by `gedit`. But this would work only if `gedit` is the first application listed in the `bookmark:group` for that particular file. If you've edited the file previously with some other application that writes to `recently-used.xbel`, you may not catch that file.

```
    <bookmark:groups>
      <bookmark:group>geany</bookmark:group>
      <bookmark:group>gedit</bookmark:group>
    </bookmark:groups>
```

Anyway, this is the output of the `grep` command:

```
~/.local/share $ grep -B5 '<bookmark:group>gedit</bookmark:group>' recently-used.xbel | grep 'bookmark href=' | grep -v '///home/'
  <bookmark href="file:///usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc" added="2016-10-15T09:38:31Z" modified="2016-10-15T09:38:31Z" visited="2016-10-15T09:38:31Z">
  <bookmark href="file:///usr/share/themes/Numix/gtk-2.0/gtkrc" added="2016-10-15T09:40:25Z" modified="2016-10-15T09:40:25Z" visited="2016-10-15T09:40:25Z">
  <bookmark href="file:///usr/share/themes/Lubuntu-default/gtk-3.0/gtk-lubuntu.css" added="2016-10-27T03:26:38Z" modified="2016-10-27T03:26:38Z" visited="2016-10-27T03:26:38Z">
  <bookmark href="file:///etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini.dpkg-old" added="2016-11-14T02:03:44Z" modified="2016-11-14T02:03:44Z" visited="2016-11-14T02:03:44Z">
  <bookmark href="file:///etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini" added="2016-11-14T02:04:05Z" modified="2016-11-14T02:04:05Z" visited="2016-11-14T02:04:05Z">
~/.local/share $
```

Comment: When I copied and pasted the command it generated an error on my Ubuntu 16.04: `$ ~/.local/share $ grep -B5 '<bookmark:group>gedit</bookmark:group>' recently-used.xbel | grep 'bookmark href=' | grep -v '///home/'
bash: /home/rick/.local/share: Is a directory`

Comment: What about something simpler like just `grep '<bookmark:group>gedit</bookmark:group>' recently-used.xbel`? Does that also not work? What are the file attributes for `recently-used.xbel` on your system? Mine are `-rw-------` (also 16.04).

Answer (score 0):

All `sudo` invocations are logged by default, not just `sudo gedit`. See `/var/log/auth.log`, or in modern systems, `journalctl $(which sudo)`. Similarly, for `pkexec`: `journalctl $(which pkexec)`.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/498379/158442) has an example of `sudo` appearing in `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Jul 16 11:50:56 laptop sudo: mv : 3 incorrect password attempts ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/mv ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/env -u LANGUAGE LC_MESSAGES=C /bin/sh /tmp/tmpBHXhYV/:script:
```

What you need is `COMMAND=...` section.

Comment: I don't invoke gedit using sudo. I always used to use gksu until recently. Using the command: 1$ journalctl $(which gksu)` results in `-- No entries --` using the same with `sudo` parameter only lists 23 entries from today none of which contain `gksu`. Am I to surmise there is no log file of `gksu gedit` on system files?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix `gksu` by itself doesn't do any authentication, it's essentially a wrapper around `su` or `sudo`. See if `su` has any `auth.log` entries.

Comment: $ journalctl $(which su)
-- No entries --

Comment: Hmm, then I need to install `gksu` to see where it does dump logs. One more reason not to use `gksu` or `gksudo`, where plain `sudo -i` works fine.

Comment: I just got .bashrc copied over to /root so sudo -i gives me nice colours tonight. I thought sudo for editing was persona non-grata though.

Comment: `sudo` for GUI programs is frowned upon because `sudo` doesn't reset some environment variables (like `$HOME`) by default. `sudo -i` does, so that's what I always use: `sudo -i <gui-command>`

Comment: I use `sudo -i` to elevate to a `#` prompt and just go on my merry way.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix then you lose much of the logging and fine-grained control with individual `sudo` invocations. I don't blame you, I always have a `sudo -i` terminal open somewhere.